# Android google maps location manager not working in SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently trying to include the google maps into my app. The main aim is to move the camera automatically to the current location of the device with a zoom after the map was loaded.

For this I need a location manager. In the below code I'm trying to implement one, but without success. I also tried to pass the context from a fragment class.

But still I'm getting this message from eclipse: The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Navigation

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Navigation extends SupportMapFragment {

private GoogleMap map;
private Context mContext;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation, null, false);
    getContextFromConfig();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    return v;
}

private void getContextFromConfig()
{
    ContextConfig config = new ContextConfig();
    mContext = config.getContext();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Google Maps is not available.");
    }

    if (map != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("snippet"));
    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //set map type
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);      

    // Show the current location in Google Map        
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSystemService()` is a method of `Context`, not of `Fragment`. You probably want to do this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

or this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I get the following Exception, when I use your code: StackOverFlowError

Comment: Well, you'll need to figure out an appropriate context to use that doesn't lead to recursive calls. Maybe when you call `getActivity()`, it calls `onCreateView()` again, which causes your code to call `getActivity()` again, and so on. Maybe you should be calling your `setUpMap()` in some later method (like `onActivityCreated()` or `onStart()`).